# Google Dart for building mobile apps

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I have recently learnt core dart. Now I want to use Dart for creating Mobile App POC.
Please suggest would it be good to use Framework like Rikulo etc for this purpose?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 0):

Rikulo's Bootjack is Bootstrap 3 with the JavaScript based widgets ported to Dart.
Bootstrap 3 is optimized for mobile so this should work.

I don't know Rikulo UI though.

I think this question is highly opinion based so it would be a good idea to specify more clearly what your requirements are.

Comment: To be specific, I am trying to build a mobile app that will perform operations like --- Identify users geographical location, display a map with radius of lets say 2kms from user's current location. Display all restaurants available in that area as map pointers. On pointers tap display restaurant information like address, phone no. etc. (with an option to dial number), search menus and read / write / share reviews. I want to extend my learning in dart using this.

Comment: This criteria are not against or in favor of a specific framework. I think it's best if you just try it out and find out for yourself if you like it. Do you know any frameworks from other web projects you liked? i.e People coming from Angular.js will probably prefer Angular.dart.